# How to image RedHat (or CentOS 7)

Tags: rhel, disk-image, clonezilla

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create an image of a RedHat 7.6 system and restore it to another system with exactly the same hardware (in this case a 2TB Raid-0 system).

We had previously done this with CentOS 6.10, using Clonezilla. By editing out the UUID entries in grub.conf, as well as deleting the eth0-3 entries in the network scripts, we were able to successfully replicate the image to other identically configured systems.

However, the same process is failing now that we've migrated to RedHat 7.6. It gets as far as the GUI interface, but stops before it shows enter username display and finally drops into a command line (emergency mode).

Can anyone advice how to successfully clone a RedHat 7.6 image?

Edit: when it drops into the command line, it's in emergency mode. 
Also, here are the error messages from the report generated:

```
Job dev-mapper-rhel\x2droot.devise/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-rhel\x2droot\device.
```

Comment: if it gets to the command line... and can you log in?  then it sounds like it was successful except for the graphics which is likely a systemd thing; one would want to have done `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` prior to creating and propagating a *gold image* to keep things simplified... if you can boot and log in at the console on the cloned system it was successful.  Then do a `systemctl isolate graphical.target` or `init 5` and deal with resulting [nouveau] problems which it sounds like it what you have

Comment: No, can't login - I think it's in emergency mode. e.g. if I try "su" it's a command not found. But I will give your suggestions a try.

Comment: Strange. I did as you suggest, and the original system boots into a prompt, but the target system still boots into the same GUI with the spinner that drops into an emergency command lin.